# Bordered box effect on hover

Tags: jquery, mouseover, mousemove, mouseout

I have an aesthetic piece of functionality I am trying to create.

The "look" is a box, which has lots of moving about borders when the box is hovered over. This is the design graphic:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/pF779SC.png]

The solution I have is that `.on('mousemove')` a new div with a border is created. The new div, `.created-x`, has a `top` and `left` position randomly positions between `-10` and `10`. The box fades in and after 500 milliseconds it is faded out and subsequently destroyed.

It's OK/getting there.

Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/adgndLqe/13/

But I am having the following issues:

#### 1. When the cursor is static over the box, `mousemove` doesn't trigger. I need it to keep triggering whenever the cursor is over the box, regardless of movement.

I'm triggering the effects as such:

```
$(".box .inner").on("mousemove", function () {
```

*How can I make this trigger whenever the hover is over the div?*

#### 2. Too many boxes

Because it generates on every mousemove, it created a bordered box for every pixel moved. Obviously it's overkill. In the graphic above you can see there are only about 6 boxes maximum. Mine is a lot heavier.

*How can I reduce the number of boxes created so it does not trigger on every pixel moved but say, every 3 or 5 pixels moved to reduce the number of boxes?*

Comment: on `mouseover` and create and `setInterval` might work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>My solution ended up being very similar to [tonoslfx's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30670295/1064325) / [ioum's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30670360/1064325). But I tried to make less changes and more explanations.</sub>

The problem was that the effect should be executed independently of `mousemove`, while hovering a box. So, instead of placing the effect code on `mousemove`, I've placed it on a `setInterval` inside the `mouseenter`. Make sure that the code inside the `setInterval` can't directly access the `mouseenter`'s `this` due to scope change, so an auxiliar variable is needed to work (thanks to closure).

Additionally, when the user leaves the box, the effect should be stopped. So, on `mouseleave`, we should `clearInterval`. But, sometimes, the events don't occur properly: it may happen to have two `mouseenter` in a box without a `mouseleave`, leading to an infinite running effect. To resolve that, we should also `clearInterval` before we call the next `setInterval`, so we guarantee that the old one won't run for ever.

Finally, to have specify how many borders the effect has, you could have a configured value - let's say, `6` - stored on a variable - let's call it `maxBorderCount`. Then, you can work with the interval set on `setInterval`. If you create a border on every `100` milliseconds, and fade them down after `500` milliseconds, you'll have a maximum of `5` *solid* borders being shown. In other words, if you create a border on every `100` milliseconds, and fade them down after `100 * maxBorderCount`, you'll have a maximum of `maxBorderCount` *solid* borders bein shown.

Please, see the [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adgndLqe/33/):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var counter = 0;
    var maxBorderCount = 6;
    var borderInterval = undefined;
    $(".box .inner").on("mouseenter", function () {
        clearInterval(borderInterval);
        var superThis = this;
        borderInterval = setInterval(function() {
            // Generate top and left position;
            var randomTop = Math.floor(Math.random() * 21) - 10;
            randomTop = randomTop + 'px';

            var randomLeft = Math.floor(Math.random() * 21) - 10;
            randomLeft = randomLeft + 'px';

            // Create unique id
            counter++;
            var current = "created-" + counter;

            // Create the div (max of ten)
            $(superThis).append("<div id='" + current + "' style='display:none;border:1px solid #fff;width:100%;min-height:170px;position:absolute;top:" + randomTop + ";left:" + randomLeft + ";'></div>");
            $('#' + current).fadeIn('fast');

            // Destroy the div after a set time
            setTimeout(function () {
                // destroy
                $('#' + current).fadeOut('fast');
                $('#' + current).remove();
            }, 100 * maxBorderCount);
        }, 100);
    }).on("mouseleave", function() {
        clearInterval(borderInterval);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function () {
    var counter = 0;
    var myinterval = 0;
    var current;

    function _boxes($this) {

        var randomTop = Math.floor(Math.random() * 21) - 10;
        randomTop = randomTop + 'px';

        var randomLeft = Math.floor(Math.random() * 21) - 10;
        randomLeft = randomLeft + 'px';

        // Create unique id
        counter++;
        var current = "created-" + counter;

        // Create the div (max of ten)
        $this.append("<div id='" + current + "' style='display:none;border:1px solid #fff;width:100%;min-height:170px;position:absolute;top:" + randomTop + ";left:" + randomLeft + ";'></div>");
        $('#' + current).fadeIn('fast');

        // Destroy the div after a set time
        setTimeout(function () {
            // destroy
            $('#' + current).fadeOut('fast');
            $('#' + current).remove();

        }, 500);

    }

    $(".box .inner").on("mouseenter", function () {

        var $this = $(this);

        clearInterval(myinterval);

        myinterval = setInterval(function () {
            _boxes($this)
        }, 100);

    }).on('mouseleave', function () {
        clearInterval(myinterval);
    });

});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the expected result of this was but it really doesn't work, in fact it's kinda worse than the original. Now, it only creates one border at a time (I still want it to create more than one at a time, as specified up to perhaps 6) and once you mouseout it goes haywire and creates thousands of borders and keeps on going https://jsfiddle.net/adgndLqe/27/

Comment: Perfect thank you. Can you add some detail to explain how you came up with the answer/what changes you made to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I would change your approach to use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. Then, while the cursor is over a box set an interval that adds borders. Clear the interval when the cursor leaves. This takes care of both creating the border even without cursor movement, and, depending on how you set the interval for border creation, controls how many border boxes are shown.

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/7Lprnqcv/)

Answer (score -1):

You have to use mouseenter.
Check this example: https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

Comment: Please test this in the JSFiddle. You will see that it does not achieve the desired effect at all.